# Angular typescript:combine 2 api calls in one promise

Tags: angular, typescript

So at the minute I have two methods in my service that make API calls as below.
They both return the same type of object as JSON, which is a Control

How can I combine them in a way that the method does do "getControls", then do "getControlsECC" and then add them together and return?

```
getControls(): Promise<Control[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.controlsUrl)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json() as Control[])
           .catch(this.handleError);
}

getControlsECC(): Promise<Control[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.controlsECC)
         .toPromise()
         .then(response => response.json() as Control[])
         .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
doBoth() {
  return forkJoin(
    this.getControls().pipe(map(response => response.json())),
    this.getControlsECC().pipe(map(response => response.json())),
  ).toPromise()
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

getControls() {
    return this.http.get<Control[]>(this.controlsUrl);
}

getControlsECC() {
  return this.http.get<Control[]>(this.controlsECC);
}
```